# Unable to execute the script in SQLCMD mode in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to call a `.sql` file in a stored procedure using `sqlcmd` mode.

The requirement is to pass the `.sql` file as a parameter value to the `cmd` script which I have been able to achieve, here is the code which is working fine:

```
declare @x sysname
set @x = 'C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\testing.sql'

:OUT $(TEMP)\GetServerName1.sql
PRINT ':SETVAR FilePath'+ ' ' + @x
GO
:OUT stdout

:r $(TEMP)\GetServerName1.sql
GO
:r $(FilePath)
```

When I try to wrap this code in a stored procedure, it is causing a "fatal error".

When I run it without wrapping it in a stored procedure, it is doing its job with no errors.

When I looked into the stored procedure I found this code:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[testing]
as
   declare @x sysname
   set @x = 'C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\testing.sql'

   PRINT ':SETVAR FilePath'+ ' ' + @x
```

It seems like the `sqlcmd` code disappears automatically. I have no clue why it is happening.

Can anyone help in letting me know how to wrap the above code in a stored procedure.

Thanks Saurav

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is terminated by the GO keyword, which works as a batch terminator. You cannot use GO in stored procedures. For ways of dealing with this, please refer to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d015786e-a69b-4fc1-b752-d10a85c2399e/use-of-go-in-a-stored-procedure?forum=transactsql) thread. Maybe try storing the procedure without GO?